# Is it correct and natural to translate: "journeys of the stars" -> "viaggi di stelle" "path of stars" -> "cammino delle stelle"?

Tags: translation

And what if "Stars" is a group's name? Can "viaggi di stelle" also mean "Stars' journeys"?

I am working on a title for an article I write. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you give us a bit more information about this article? Maybe we can help you better if we get a bit of context.
Also, Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! What do you mean with "a group's name"?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE from me too. `:-)` If by “Stars’ journeys” you mean something along the line of “Star wars”, it can be better translated as “Viaggi stellari” or “Viaggi tra le stelle” — the latter being the clearest option, in my view.

Comment: @FerdinandBardamu +1 for "Viaggi tra le stelle". To the OP, it's something like "Journeys through the stars". Is that the meaning you wanted to give?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Litterally *journey of the stars* corresponds to *i viaggi delle stelle*. As a  title of an article it sounds a bit poetic or fantastic. In a more scientific context you would probably say  *traiettoria delle stelle* o *movimento delle stelle*.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I am writing a story about road adventures of a duet band named Stelle.  (I'm sorry I confused it with the word "article" before).  Iknow it's the Italian for "stars", and think rather than putting "the journeys of Stelle" as the title, it'd be more interesting (and romantic) if I write it in Italian and explain about the meaning in the introduction.  Josh61's answer sounds right to me.  But may I ask a bit more explanation on why adding "i" in "i viaggi"?  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: In Italian, unlike in English, we usually use the definite  (or an indefinite) article before a noun even though we are referring to a generic context. Being a title, though, I think you can use whatever expression you may prefer.